# Objective-c read image from sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(PhotoImage, 100);
    NSString* queryString = ; 
    [SQLiteAccess insertWithSQL:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into images (photo) values ('%@')", imageData] // photo - blob column
]; // i use class SQLiteaccess
```

insert is normally
but when i read image from sqlite

```
NSArray *photoSelectArray = [SQLiteAccess selectManyRowsWithSQL: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select photo from places where id=%i", idPlace]]; 
NSDictionary *imageDataDic = [photoSelectArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithData: [imageDataDic objectForKey:@"photo"]];
 UIImage *cachedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
```

i have an error - SIGABRT `(Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e5c46d0')`

p.s. class for easy access to sqlite
- SQLiteAccess.h - http://pastebin.com/BFxFry7T
- SQLiteAccess.m - http://pastebin.com/m67yNVLm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think the problem is here:

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into images (photo) values ('%@')", imageData]]; // i use class SQLiteaccess`

When using SQLite directly, you should set the binary data by `sqlite3_bind_blob()`, but you're actually setting the binary data as string.

So when you get back the data, it's not a binary data, it's a `String` object, of course, an string object don't response to `-[NSData bytes]`

---

Meanwhile I think you should check the field type in your SQLite DB file. Does the `photo` is actually set to `blob`.